# Using SSH authentification with libgit2

Tags: c, git, ssh, libgit2, libssh2

I am trying to authenticate against a git server with `libgit2` using SSH keys.
So far, this is working for URLs like `ssh://myuser@host.domain:1234/dirs/repo.git`, where my application accepts the URL as an argument.

However, if I remove the username from the URL (i.e. `ssh://host.domain:1234/dirs/repo.git`) the connection fails, *even if I set the user name programmatically* (see below).

Consider the following MCVE for a program that checks whether a certain repository is reachable (no error checks except for the necessary):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <git2.h>
#include <git2/sys/repository.h>

int my_cred_cb(git_cred **out, const char *url,
    const char *username_from_url, unsigned int allowed_types, void *payload)
{
  uid_t uid = geteuid();             // Get effective user ID
  struct passwd* pw = getpwuid(uid); // Get password file entry

  char privkeypath[strlen(pw->pw_dir) + 13];
  strcpy(privkeypath, pw->pw_dir);
  strcat(privkeypath, "/.ssh/id_rsa"); // "~user/.ssh/id_rsa"

  char publkeypath[strlen(privkeypath) + 5]; 
  strcpy(publkeypath, privkeypath);
  strcat(publkeypath, ".pub"); // "~user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"

  const char* username = (username_from_url != NULL ? username_from_url : pw->pw_name);

  printf("Using username: %s, priv key %s and publ key %s\n", username, privkeypath, publkeypath);
  return git_cred_ssh_key_new(out, username, publkeypath, privkeypath, ""); // No passphrase for keys
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  git_remote* remote = NULL;
  git_repository* repo = NULL;
  git_remote_callbacks cbs;
  const git_error* err;

  if (argc != 2) return EXIT_FAILURE;

  git_libgit2_init();
  git_repository_new(&repo);
  git_remote_create_anonymous(&remote, repo, argv[1]);
  git_remote_init_callbacks(&cbs, GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_VERSION);
  cbs.credentials = my_cred_cb;

  if (git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_FETCH, &cbs, NULL, NULL)) {
    err = giterr_last();
    printf ("Error %d: %s\n", err->klass, err->message);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  git_libgit2_shutdown();
  printf("git repo exists and is reachable.\n");
}
```

This can be compiled with `gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -o myapp main.c -lssh2 -lgit2`, assuming the include and library paths are set properly.

Now consider the output for different URLs:

```
$ ./myapp ssh://myuser@host.domain:1234/dirs/repo.git
Using username: myuser, priv key /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa and publ key /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
git repo exists and is reachable.
```

And now the failing case:

```
$ ./myapp ssh://host.domain:1234/dirs/repo.git # Note the missing user name
Using username: myuser, priv key /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa and publ key /home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Error 23: callback returned unsupported credentials type
```

I do not understand why I receive this error, since I pass the exact same information to the library (why is it "unsupported credentials type" in the first place?).

Even worse, I usually use `Host` entries in my `~/.ssh/config`, such that instead of putting `host.domain:1234` I can simply use `myhost` (e.g. `git clone ssh://myhost/dirs/repo.git` works just fine). For my application, this is the output:

```
$ ./myapp ssh://myhost/dirs/repo.git
Error 12: failed to resolve address for myhost: Name or service not known
```

It looks like `libgit2` does not configure `libssh2` to read in the ssh-config. That's a related, yet probably a different problem. Still I feel these two problems belong together.

Summarizing my questions:

1. How do I pass the username to the git credentials programmatically (vs. in the URL)?
2. How do I tell `libgit2` to retrieve information from my ssh-config before attempting to connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These really are two separate unrelated questions.

1. You should be checking the `allowed_types` parameter in your callback and only return a `git_cred_ssh_key_new` credential if it contains `GIT_CREDTYPE_SSH_KEY`. The backend is probably requesting a credential of type `GIT_CREDTYPE_USERNAME` because the URL doesn't have one. In that case you should be returning a credential created by `git_cred_username_new`. Your callback will be called twice, once to get the username, and a second time to create the ssh credential.
2. Reading config settings from your OpenSSH config file at ~/.ssh/config isn't supported by libgit2 because it isn't support by libssh2. If you want to read settings from there, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Yes, in fact, I also realized later that these two questions are rather unrelated. But I will keep them as is so that your answer still fits. I find the documentation rather bad regarding the allowed types, also considering that types are defined as `git_credtype_t` enumeration, but the callback only takes an `unsigned int` and no hint is given where to find the allowed types. But this gave me a tremendous good pointer for further digging and I was already able to solve #1, thank you!

Comment: FTR it's defined as `unsigned int` because it's a set of OR-ed flags, and IIRC a compiler could complain that you're creating values not covered by the underlying enum. Please don't quote me on that though.

Comment: @andreee how did you solve #1 ? Can you post as another answer in this question your solution?